# For Loop Exit Condition (size_t vs. int)

Tags: c++, for-loop, int, size-t

When I put the following in my program:

```
for (size_t i = VectorOfStructs.size()-1; i > 0; i--)
```

It works correctly but does "i" will never equal 0.
 So, I cannot access the first element (VectorOfStructs[0]).

If I change it to:

```
for (size_t i = VectorOfStructs.size()-1; i > -1; i--)
```

The program doesn't even enter the for loop! But, if I change it to the following:

```
for (int i = VectorOfStructs.size()-1; i > -1; i--)
```

It works exactly as I want it to (Iterates through all the elements).

**So, my questions are:**

**(A) Why does the 2nd code snippet fail to execute?**

**(B) Why does the 3rd code snippet execute accordingly while the 2nd doesn't?**

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: size_t is an unsigned type, it is never larger than `(size_t)-1`.  Most compilers generate a warning for this kind of code, you'll want to turn that on.

Comment: Perhaps better: `for (auto iter = VectorOfStructs.rbegin(); iter != VectorOfStructs.rend(); ++iter) { /* use *iter */ }`

Comment: If you want to iterate backwards, you should check for `i-- > 0` in the second part of the `for` loop and remove the third part of the for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second example uses `size_t` as type for `i`, which is an *unsigned* type, thus it can never have negative values; this also means that it cannot be properly compared with `-1`

But `(int)-1` is bit-represented as `0xFFFFFFFF`, which represents a rather large number (`2^32-1`) for `size_t`. `i>0xFFFFFFFF` can never be true, since `0xFFFFFFF` is the largest value a `size_t` can ever hold.

The 3rd example uses `signed int` (which allows for negative numbers and therefore the test succeeds).

This one should work:

```
for (size_t i = VectorOfStructs.size(); i-- > 0;) {
  use(VectorOfStructs[i]);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, use the "--> operator" (see the related stackoverflow question) instead

Comment: @BenjaminLindley :facepalm: /me won't use *canonical* again...

Comment: @KABoissonneault hey, I already had fixed that before your comment...

Answer (score 4):

All loops go forward, even the ones that go backwards.

What you want is either this:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0, e = VectorOfStructs.size(); i != e; ++i)
{
    std::size_t const ri = e - i - 1;

    // use "VectorOfStructs[ri]"
}
```

Or better:

```
for (auto rit = VectorOfStructs.rbegin(); rit != VectorOfStructs.rend(); ++rit)
{
    // use "*rit"
}
```

(Your second snippet fails because `i` is unsigned, so `-1` is converted to the same type as `i` and becomes the maximal representable value, so the comparison is always true. By contrast, `i` is signed in the third snippet.)

Comment: Do you have a link for the "use()" function? I have never heard of that and a search turns up nothing.

Comment: @Donald: That's just a placeholder for your code!

Comment: I do not know how to use "*rit". If I do: int Counter=*rit; It gives me "error: no sutiable conversion function from "VectorOfStructs" to "int" exists"

Comment: @Donald: Iterators give you access to the vector elements, not the vector subscripts.

Answer (score 3):

In second one you comparing variable 'i' with -1 , and here it is of type size_t and size can not be in negative so it fails.

In third one , 'i' is integer type and integer has range from -32568 to +32567 (for int=2 byte in a system)

**Overall   `size_t` variable can not have negative values because a physical memory will have its existence in the system**

Comment: though `int` usually has 32bit == 4byte

Comment: earlier machines uses 2byte to store Integer variable but now machines store it in 2byte/4byte  depending upon the **Architecture of System**

Comment: sure; it's just *very uncommon* these days;

Comment: btw, could you elaborate on how *non-physical memory* would allow for negative sizes?

Comment: there does not exist any _non-physical_ memory , as if you think that about virtual memory then it also have some _physical_ existence

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the 2nd code snippet fail to execute?

`size_t` is unsigned, so it is by definition never negative. So your loop condition is always true. The variable "wraps around" to the maximum value.

Answer (score 1):

`size_t` is an unsigned type so `-1` is the maximum value `size_t` can take. In the second snippet `size_t` can't be greater than this maximum value so the loop isn't entered.

On the other hand, `int` is a signed type so the comparison to `-1` is as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Int and size_t are both integer types but int can hold negatives as well as positives.
int ranges from -2^31 -1 to 2^31 -1 while size_t ranges from 0 to 2^32 -1

Now, when you write something like int a = -1 it is indeed -1 but when you do so with size_t you get the max int 2^32 -1

So in the 2nd snippet no size_t value will ever exceed -1 as it really 2^32 -1

In the 3rd snippet the type compared is int and when int is compared to -1 it sees it as -1 so it executes the way you planned

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler sees `i > -1` and notices that the subexpressions `i` and `-1` have different types, it converts them both to a *common type*.  If the two types (`std::size_t` and `int`) have the same number of bits, which appears to be the case for your compiler, the common type is the unsigned one (`std::size_t`).  So the expression turns out to be equivalent to `i > (std::size_t)-1`.  But of course `(std::size_t)-1` is the maximum possible value of a `size_t`, so the comparison is always false.

Most compilers have a warning about a comparison that is always true or always false for reasons like this.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you compare 'signed' and 'unsigned' the 'signed' values are converted to 'unsigned', first. That covers (#1) and (#2), having a problems with 'unsigned(0-1)' and 'some unsigned' > 'unsigned max'.

However, making it work by forcing a 'signed'/'signed' compare (#3), you loose 1/2 of the 'unsigned' range.

You may do:

```
for(size_t n = vector.size(); n; /* no -- here */ ) {
   --n;
   // vector[n];
}
```

Note: unsigned(-1) is on many systems the biggest unsigned integer value.