# C++ reverse 'for' loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, unsigned

I have a vector:

```
std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3};
```

And I want to make a reverse `for` loop. It works, when I write:

```
for(int i = vec.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl; // 2, 1, 0
}
```

But I get a very large number (like 18446744073709223794) if I write:

```
for(size_t i = vec.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

But they both work when I write:

```
for(int i = 0; i < vec.size() - 1; ++i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl; // 1, 2, 3
}

// Or
for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size() - 1; ++i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl; // 1, 2, 3
}
```

Why do I get the wrong size of the vector when I use `size_t`?

I think there is a problem with the conversion.

Comment: Are you aware of the iterators? They are meant for this job.

Comment: Use `vec.rbegin()` and `vec.rend()` to iterate backwards.

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes, but I want to know why my code does not work so

Comment: Sorry, you got two "agrees" on your comment, so the misunderstanding is probably on my side. But what do you mean by "I want to know why my code does not work so" ? Why your code does not work as it is? Why your code does not work by using iterators?

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes, I just wanted to know, why my code does not work with size_t.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Covered this in my answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over a vector in reverse direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205720/iterating-over-a-vector-in-reverse-direction)

Comment: @Nick I were not looking for how to make for loop with reverse. I just wanted to know why me code does not work with `size_t`

Comment: @SKIP *"As you've noted, the problem with a condition of i >= 0 when it's unsigned is that the condition is always true."* - First line of first answer

Comment: But if you prefer then there's always: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31659368/for-loop-exit-condition-size-t-vs-int

Comment: Why *should* your code work? Asking why it doesn't is just asking for another definition of how the language works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Let the compiler tell you what's wrong!

If you compiled your program with warnings enabled, the compiler would [tell](https://godbolt.org/z/amEvtc) you something like this:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':

7:43: warning: comparison of unsigned expression in '>= 0' is always true [-Wtype-limits]
    7 |     for(std::size_t i = vec.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      |                                         ~~^~~~
```

Why is that? It's because [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) is an *unsigned* type in C++; it only represents non-negative numbers. Read more about turning on warnings and why it's important: [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings)

### So, how *should* we reverse-iterate?

I've decided to split my answer here off to a separate question, independent of OP's bug. Please [go read it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62361803/1593077).

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. Why you use in option 1 `std::crbegin` and `std::crend` is there will be any difference If I use `std::rbegin` and `std::rend`?

Comment: @SKIP: `crbegin()` and `crend() gives you `vector::const_iterator`s, guaranteeing you wont change the vector's content through the iterator.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `size_t` is an **unsigned** integer, i.e. it can only have positive values. When you decrease 0 for an unsigned type an underflow happens and the result is usually the largest integer representable by that type, e.g. 18446744073709223794 in your case. Finally the check for `i >= 0` is always true for any unsigned type and your loop will never terminate.

Comment: Why isn't it an uneven number (e.g. like -1 / 255 for 8-bit integers)?

Comment: `size_t(-1)` should be (on 64 bit systems) 2^64-1, i.e. an uneven number. I guess OP just picked any number the for loop printed, no necessarily the first one.